# how to write global router-function in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using Vue.js with Nuxt.js, but I got a problem in router's functions.

In the pure Vue, i can write in `main.js` like this:

```
val route = new Router({
   routes:{
      [...]
   }
})

route.beforeEach(to,from,next){
    //do something to validate
}
```

And how to do the same in nuxt.js ? I can not find any file like `main.js`.

Also, all i know is to deal with the `pages` folder to achieve router, I can not set the redirect path

please help, thx :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's possible to create a **plugin** for Nuxt that can add a global router function. This can be a useful way to extend the router capabilities of your Nuxt application.

First, create a `plugins/route.js` file:

```
// Nuxt <= 2.x
export default ({ app }) => {
   // Every time the route changes (fired on initialization too)
   app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
     //do something to validate
   })
}
```

or

```
// Nuxt >= 3.x
export default ({ app }) => {
   // Every time the route changes (fired on initialization too)
   app.$router.afterEach((to, from) => {
     //do something to validate
   })
}
```

Then update your `nuxt.config.js` file with:

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/route']
```

---

More details about plugins:

- Nuxt 2.x : https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
- Nuxt 3.x : https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: @JackyWong how do you do it with middleware?

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this helpful snippet of code. I was trying to make a middleware for this

Comment: Wish I could give you a hug. thank you so much for this. anyway, I use Nuxt3, the code needs a little adjustment to this: app.$router.afterEach

Answer (score 10):

If anybody might be still interested, it's possible to setup global middleware in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```js
router: { middleware: ['foo'] },
```

then in your `middleware/foo.js` you do whatever...

```js
export default function({ route, from, store, redirect }) {}
```

**Beware:** You can't use this for static sites (nuxt generate), because middleware is not executed on page load, but only on subsequent route changes. Thanks @ProblemsOfSumit for pointing that out.

Comment: I guess if you use SPA mode, you don't have middleware, right?

Comment: For future reference: You can use middleware in SPA mode. For SPAs it is only executed on the client side.

See this discussion on github for all the gotchas: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2653

Comment: For static sites, you can't use middleware because they are not executed on page load, only on subsequent route changes.

Comment: If you reload any of your routes directly, they are also not called

Comment: what is the difference between a nuxt plugin and router middleware, from what I see they seem to do the exact same thing?

Comment: Plugins have much broader scope of use as opposed to middlewares which are closely connected to routing.