# trigger function after mounting any page in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Is it possible to write middleware in Nuxt to be triggered after mounting any page.

If I use the following middleware

```js
export default function ({ app }) {
  if (!process.server) {
    app.$somePluginFunction()
  }
}
```

it is triggered when navigating to that page, thus before mounting it. That is not what I am looking for.

I also know you can use the `mounted()` hook on an individual page, which is what I want, but I don't want to write the same `mounted()` hook to every page in my app manually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

There is many way to trigger a function before route change:

First use in default layout

```
// layout/default.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    $route () {
      console.log('route changed', this.$route)
    }
  },
}
```

Second use before route:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name !== 'Login' && !isAuthenticated) next({ name: 'Login' })
  else next()
})
```

Third write plugin like this:

[how to write global router-function in nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509472/how-to-write-global-router-function-in-nuxt-js/46063580)

And write mixin like this :

[Run function AFTER route fully rendered in Nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695816/run-function-after-route-fully-rendered-in-nuxt-js)